# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier when using getElementById to read click event

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the accordion function of Twitter Bootstrap to display more or less text for a certain field in my database called "description".

I am receiving the javascript error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Here is the php/html:

```
<span class="description_text">{{ substr($artist->description,0,100) }}</span>
        <a id="more" class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne" style="display:block;">See More...</a>
        <span id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse"><span class="description_text">{{substr($artist->description,101)}}</span></span>
        <a id="less" class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne" style="display:none;">...See Less</a>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
document.getElementById("more").addEventListener('click',function() {

    document.getElementById('less').style.display = "block";  

    document.getElementById('more').style.display = "none";    
}

document.getElementById("less").addEventListener('click',function() {

    document.getElementById('more').style.display = "block";   

    document.getElementById('less').style.display = "none";   
}
```

The idea is I want the remainder of the description field to appear when clicking the "See More" link, then having the "See More" link disappear and have the "See Less" link appear.  When clicking see less, I would like the text to go away and then have the "see more" link appear again.

Right now, I am receiving the error above, and the "see less" button isn't appearing when the text "expands".  I am coding this using Laravel 4.

Comment: Make a http://jsfiddle.net out of it

Comment: I cannot get this to work correctly with the bootstrap files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't closed either of your `.addEventListener` methods.

```
document.getElementById("more").addEventListener('click',function() {

    document.getElementById('less').style.display = "block";  

    document.getElementById('more').style.display = "none";    
}); //here

document.getElementById("less").addEventListener('click',function() {

    document.getElementById('more').style.display = "block";   

    document.getElementById('less').style.display = "none";   
}); //and here
```

Comment: No problem. In the future, you may want to use http://jshint.com to debug your code. I find it immensely helpful.

Comment: Ok, I closed the methods, and the error is gone, but I am still seeing the same functionality issues I described in the question.  Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Hmm, very strange that it isn't working for me...any idea what could be going on?  The see more button isn't disappearing and the see less button isn't appearing.

Comment: In reference to the line: document.getElementById("more").addEventListener('click',function() {

I am getting the error:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method "addEventListener" of null

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue.  I needed to put the event listener javascript at the bottom of the page.  This made the "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null" error go away.  Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This is probably because the element with the id of "more" had not yet been created when the javascript ran. Therefore, the `getElementById("more")` returned `null`.